# Plotting the index with any column

Tags: pandas

How to plot any column with the **index** of that dataframe.
I have already tried with **df.index** but it is giving an error
Below i have added how it looks like.

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58CZU.png)

Comment: It is having two index so I dont know how to remove one

Comment: can you add a sample of your data

Answer (score 0):

as I understand, your index has two levels: you can xhoose one using:

```py
x = df.index.get_level_values(1)
y = df[col]
plt.plot(x, y.values)
```

where `col` is your column, you cound change the index chosen by changing the level argument from 0 to 1

Comment: It is giving Dataerror:  No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: use level 1 instead of 0  `x = df.index.get_level_values(1)`, that's because the level 1 is the one that contains your dates, I changed my response to take that into account

Comment: x = df.index.get_level_values(1) .I have used the same

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with this much information, `Dataerror: No numeric types to aggregate` is supposed to occur if you are grouping some values or aggregating data, which is obviously not the case here, or probably your date index is of type string

Comment: I think it must have worked for numeric values in the index but for this case of datetime index it is giving an error

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using `df.set_index(df.index.get_level_values(1))` and then plotting simply using `df.index()` for the date index.